# R-CNN: looking for REPO where FC for classification is retrainable

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm studying different object detection algorithms for my interest. 
The main reference are **Andrej Karpathy's slides** on object detection [slides here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture8.pdf).

I would like to start from some reference, in particular something which allows me to directly test some of the network mentioned on my data (mainly consisting in onboard cameras of car and bike races).

Unfortunately **I already used some pretrained network** ([repo forked from JunshengFu one](https://github.com/tomwarrens/vehicle-detection), where I slightly adapt Yolo to my use case), **but the classification accuracy is rather poor**, I guess because there were not many training instances of racing cars like Formula 1.

For this reason I would like to retrain the networks and here is where I'm finding the most issues:

properly training some of the networks requires either hardware (powerful GPUs) or time I don't have so I was wondering whether I could retrain just some part of the network, in particular the classification network and **if there is any repo already allowing that**.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is called fine-tuning of the network or transfer-learning. Basically you can do that for any network you find (having similar problem domains of course), and then depending on the amount of the data you have you will either fine-tune whole network or freeze some layers and train only last layers. For your case you would probably need to freeze whole network except last fully-connected layers (which you will actually replace with new ones, satisfying your number of classes), which perform classification. I don't know what library you use, but tensorflow has official [tutorial on transfer-learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining). However it's not very clear tbh.

More user-friendly tutorial you can find here by some enthusiast: [tutorial](https://kwotsin.github.io/tech/2017/02/11/transfer-learning.html). Here you can find a code repository as well. One correction you need thou is that the author performs fine-tuning of the whole network, while if you want to freeze some layers you will need to get list of the trainable variables and remove those you want to freeze and pass the resultant list to the optimizer (so he ignores removed vars), like following:

```
all_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,scope='InceptionResnetV2')
to_train = all_vars[-6:] // you better specify them by name explicitely, but this still will work
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr=0.0001)
train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss,optimizer, variables_to_train=to_train)
```

Further, tensorflow has a so called model zoo (bunch of trained models you can use for your purposes and transfer-learning). You can find it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but none of the paragraphs are helpful: I know what transfer learning is and I have already done that with an inception net (and yes, tensorflow). The point here is that networks are Fast R-CNN, Faster R-CNN, Yolo and I didn't find any repo which guided me through retraining the fully connected network for region labeling. Thank you anyway for giving more context to my question :)